# How to write ant path pattern except one path?

Tags: java, spring, ant

Spring Framework has the [AntPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) which is borrowed from Ant.

I have the following path:

- /api/index
- /api/test/random
- /api/test/another
- /api/other/1
- /api/other/2

and I will add more paths like `/api/other/other`, I'd like to ask how can I create an AntPath Pattern to match all path except the `/api/index`.

I have tried to make some tests, but none of the following works.

```
  private static final String PATTERN = "/api/*/**";

  @Test
  public void test() {
    AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
    boolean match = pathMatcher.match(PATTERN, "/api/index");
    System.out.println(match);
    match = pathMatcher.match(PATTERN, "/api/test/test");
    System.out.println(match);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [Spring AntPathMatcher Docu](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) you can add a path variable to your pattern where you can specify a Regex this path variable has to match:

```
    String PATTERN = "/api/{path:^(?!(index)$).*$}/**";
```

The above pattern for the `path` variable accepts any characters but the string `"index"`. If you want to filter out any strings containing the substring `"index"` you could change it to:

```
    String PATTERN = "/api/{path:^(?!(index)).*$}/**";


    AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
    boolean match = pathMatcher.match(PATTERN, "/api/index");
    assert match == false;
    match = pathMatcher.match(PATTERN, "/api/index/sec");
    assert match == false;
    match = pathMatcher.match(PATTERN, "/api/index4");
    assert match == false;
    match = pathMatcher.match(PATTERN, "/api/test/random");
    assert match == true;
    match = pathMatcher.match(PATTERN, "/api/test/another");
    assert match == true;
    match = pathMatcher.match(PATTERN, "/api/other/1");
    assert match == true;
    match = pathMatcher.match(PATTERN, "/api/other/2");
    assert match == true;
    match = pathMatcher.match(PATTERN, "/api/other/index");
    assert match == true;
```